# NodeJS Puppeteer Block third party cookies

Tags: node.js, cookies, puppeteer

Sorry, I couldn't find the code to block third-party cookies. The code snippet I added as an example below attracts all cookies. **I want to block third party cookies**.

```js
await page._client.send('Network.getAllCookies'));
```

Comment: third-party blocking is different than retrieving cookies. you can get 1st party cookies with `await page.cookies()` method.

Comment: while I don't see any CDP commands or launch switches for setting the browser to block 3rd party cookies, you can create a profile and manually set the browser to do that. let me know if you need details on that

Comment: @mbit Can you explain? I really need it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Retrieving 1st party cookies:

You can get first party cookies with

```js
await page.cookies()
```

#### Blocking 3rd party cookies:

To my knowledge, there is no CDP command or terminal switch for blocking 3rd party cookies. Having said that, you can create a profile and turn on 3rd party cookie blocking in that profile. You initialize the profile once and after that whenever you launch chromium with that profile the setting will be applied. This will keep the browser settings across different runs.

1. create a folder and pass it to the `userDataDir` launch option and set a reasonable amount of wait since you're going to manually interact with the browser:

   ```js
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
       headless: false,
       userDataDir: "full/path/to/created/folder"
   });
   const page = await browser.newPage();
   await page.waitFor(60000);
   await browser.close();
   ```
2. dry run your program and when chromium opens go to `Settings > Site Settings > Cookies and site data` and turn on `Block third-party cookies`

Now you can use this *initialized* profile in other runs and block 3rd party cookies.

**Note:** Keep in mind that other data (e.g. cookies) will also be stored in the profile you've created which is different from the default behavior of puppeteer that each time runs with a fresh profile. For that, you might need to consider incognito mode.